How to open H2-console in an Quarkus Application
I wanted to open H2 console to check my DB in an Quarkus Application.
I have added H2 dependency, and I am able to insert & retrieve the Database using APIs, but I'm not able to open the H2 console to view my database from an UI.
My current setup -
Dependencies in POM.xml:-
<dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-jdbc-h2</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-vertx</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-undertow</artifactId>
      <version>3.9.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-webjars-locator</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
      <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
      <version>3.6.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-agroal</artifactId>
</dependency>

Application.properties file:-
quarkus.datasource.db-kind = h2
quarkus.datasource.username = sa
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=jdbc:h2:file:./src/main/resources/ras;

**I have seen a solution here and tried to follow that and created a web.xml file in META-INF.resources.
**
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app
        PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
        "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">

<web-app>
    <display-name>My Web Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>h2-console</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.h2.server.web.WebServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>webAllowOthers</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>h2-console</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/h2/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>

`I have tried accessing http://localhost:9001/h2-console and also http://localhost:9001/h2, still it is giving an error stating "Resource not found".
Can someone please tell, how to I open h2-console. Thanks in advance. `

Have you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/a/64132441/11110455 ?

Here there's an idea to access H2 with DBeaver - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67027970/how-can-i-start-h2-in-server-mode-using-quarkus
